# What is the biggest perimeter of triangle with excircle of radius 1?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Here's an excercise from my calculus class I'm trying to wrap my head around:

Given a circle of radius $1$, does there exist the triangle with the biggest perimeter that you can inscribe in this circle? If yes, what is its perimeter?

A naive way would be to construct function which takes points and returns the perimeter and find its maximum value, but such function would need at least 3 arguments, so we must find another way.

I came up with a way to construct a function $f(x)$ with parameter $d\in\Bbb{R}$ the derivative of which is more accessible, as the function depends on one argument only. Let $d$ be the length of the first side of triangle and we're picking 2 points depending on $d$ in such a way, that those points form a vertical line through a circle, and they lie to the right of the circle's center. After a few transformations, we're able to find these points with coordinates dependent on $d\in (0,2]$:

$$A=(\sqrt{\frac{4-d^2}{4}}, \frac{d}{2}), B=(\sqrt{\frac{4-d^2}{4}},-\frac{d}{2})$$

It seems too complicated already, and it gets even worse. Now we're trying to pick the 3rd point in the circle - $C=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$. If we pick it, we get a function, that gives us the perimeter of a triangle:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{\frac{4-d^2}{4}})^2+(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{d}{2})^2} + \sqrt{(x-\sqrt{\frac{4-d^2}{4}})^2+(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{d}{2})^2}  + d$$

My plan was to find $f'(x)$ and then find $f(x)$'s maximum value, and then pick $d$ that will maximise it, but it seems infeasible (after feeding the function to WolframAlpha I get exceeded computation time)...

Is this the correct way to solve this problem? Maybe there is a simpler approach out there? Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will get $a+b+c=2R(\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C))=2(\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C))$ under the condition $A+B+C=\pi$ now you can use the Lagrange-Multiplier Method.

Comment: Great answer.  I'll add that the symmetry of the equations you wrote down from the Law of Sines tells us that Lagrange multipliers will give A,B,C such that A = B = C, so the triangle will be equilateral...

Comment: From Jensen's inequality, the mean of the sine is less than or equal to the mean of the sine, with equality only when all three angles are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a simple answer I came up with after reading one of the comments:

We have (from law of the sines) $a=2\sin\alpha$, $b=2\sin\beta$, $c=2\sin\gamma$, so $a+b+c=2(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)$ so $\frac{a+b+c}{6}=\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}{3}$ which means that now we're trying to maximise   $\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}{3}$.

$\sin x$ is concave at the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, so by Jensen's inequality we get:

$\sin(\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{3})\geq\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}{3}$

$\sin(\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{3})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ so it's constant and as it turns out for $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\frac{\pi}{3}$ the right side evaluates exactly to $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ which means that we get an equality for equirateral triangle.